# See actual results of SQL UPDATE command

Tags: update

Is there a way to get the actual results of `SQL UPDATE` command (ie the table rows *themselves*), not just get the *number* of rows (other than by converting the `UPDATE` command to a `SELECT`)? I'm using mainly Postgres and Informix, but I'd be interested to hear about other database systems that have this feature, or perhaps a particular client that supports this.

Comment: [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you'd do something like that in SQL Server.  Because an `UPDATE` is essentially old data and new data, SQL Server exposes the `deleted` and `inserted` dynamic tables.  You can work with them to get what the data looked like prior to the `UPDATE`, and after the `UPDATE`:

```
update HumanResources.Department
set GroupName = 'Testing Group Name'
output
    deleted.DepartmentID as Old_DepartmentID,
    inserted.DepartmentID as New_DepartmentID,
    deleted.Name as Old_Name,
    inserted.Name as New_Name,
    deleted.GroupName as Old_GroupName,
    inserted.GroupName as New_GroupName
where DepartmentID > 12
```

Comment: Thanks, and now I see there's also something similar in Postgres, the `RETURNING` clause.